# Android: proguard with rhino jar?

Tags: android

I have added the Rhino js-14.jar to my project and am no longer able to build with proguard.  When I attempt to build I get many messages like:

> Warning: org.mozilla.javascript.tools.debugger.ContextWindow: can't
>   find superclass or interface javax.swing.JPanel

And then the build fails with message:

> Proguard returned with error code 1. See console.

Any recommendations for how to fix this?

Comment: have u get any solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just delete the tools directory from the js-14.jar file